# How to convert a single column csv file with 660 rows & no header into a 660 element tuple/series

Tags: csv, data-manipulation, txt

Here is what I have[image]

I would like to be able to convert this into something that looks like this instead:
(09J,14A,18A,1V6,22S,2I0,2R4,32S,38S,...)

How should I go about accomplishing this simple task?

I also have it in a simple txt file as well, maybe it would be easier to do this from there, so here is what that looks like:
[image]

Comment: Please do not use images, use code element instead. See [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  In this, the use of images for code is specifically highlighted. Your question could have been written "*how do I convert a single column file to a tuple?*".

Comment: @MyICQ if I had been as clear on how to word this question correctly using the proper jargon in that way, I would not have needed to ask the question in the first place. And unless code element is something different than code, there is no code involved here, this is a step or two before the code comes in on my end.

Comment: Please note that the comment was a recommendation. As you can see in the link, it is recommended to post sample content as *text* instead of a picture, because many people that help often use copy/paste. See [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [syntax highlight](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work). By code I did not mean actual code, but a **code block**. This is explained in the links. I use three backticks followed by `none` to indicate "pure text".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may work using python.
[image]

i am reading a text file not a csv, not sure if that works with big data tho.

Comment: You should perhaps edit your question and paste python code instead of using an image. It makes it easier for others to copy/paste and use your work.